# execv system call not running as desired

Tags: linux, g++, system-calls, execv

I use Linux and while compiling any c or cpp file, I use gcc or g++ respectively in terminal.
Common syntax : `g++ program.cpp`

But now I wish to compile files using flags.
Eg: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 program.cpp`
I will use more 10 flags to compile my program. But I don't want to remember and type that while compiling in terminal.

Now I wish to create a c program involving syscalls (exec) to get my job done using below syntax:
`./compile program.cpp`

But there's some problem while using exec in my below code

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int args, char* argv[]){
    char* arguments[10]={"-std=c++11","-Wall","-Wextra","-pedantic","-Wshadow","-fsanitize=address","-fsanitize=undefined","-fstack-protector"}; //consists of flags with which i will compile the program passed as argument
    printf("%s\t %s",argv[0],argv[1]);
    if(args==2){
        arguments[8]=argv[1];
        arguments[9]=(char*)NULL;
    }else{
        printf("only one argument allowed!");// just to check if i pass arguments correctly
    }
    printf("%s\t %s",arguments[8],arguments[9]);// just to check if my arguments array is correct
    if(execv("/bin/g++",arguments)==-1){ // to my suprise this line runs before above printing lines. What is the reason/solution?
        perror("execv failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles successfully without error.
But I think execv runs even before I insert passed argument in argument array.
Because of which, program runs with error `execv failed: no such file or directory` 
Followed by the printfs.
Please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: The printing doesn't happen because the buffer is not full to force a flush and you're not using a "\n" either.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why "makefile" is not suitable?

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate further on using "\n"? Maybe what you are saying is somewhat correct but I'm not getting it :-(

Comment: Learn to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it confused me more than to help me. As a competitive programmer, I need minimal approach to get the job done only with terminal activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved the ambiguity in the above code. I made two radical changes to my code.

1. Instead of directly assigning argument strings while declaration of string array,

```
char* arguments[10]={"-std=c++11","-Wall","-Wextra","-pedantic","-Wshadow","-fsanitize=address","-fsanitize=undefined","-fstack-protector"};
```

I chose to just assign strings one by one.

```
char* arguments[10];
        arguments[0]="g++";
        arguments[1]="-Wall";
        arguments[2]="-Wextra";
and so on
```

And this fixed the segmentation faults in my code.

2. This time I used execvp() instead of execv() system call because of which I don't need to explicitly declare full path to the command `usr/bin/g++` and so on. In execvp only command name is enough.
   So my new code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int args, char* argv[]){
        char* arguments[10];
        //printf("%s\t %s\n",argv[0],argv[1]); 
        arguments[0]="g++";
        arguments[1]="-Wall";
        arguments[2]="-Wextra";
        arguments[3]="-pedantic";
        arguments[4]="-Wshadow";
        arguments[5]="-fsanitize=address";
        arguments[6]="-fsanitize=undefined";
        arguments[7]="-fstack-protector";// to add more flags make changes in this array.
        if(args==2){
                arguments[8]=argv[1];
                arguments[9]=(char*)NULL;
                if(execvp(arguments[0],arguments)==-1){
                        perror("execv failed!");
                        exit(1);
                }

        }else{
                printf("->Only one argument(c/cpp file) allowed.\n->Requtired syntax: ./compile program.cpp\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

3. Another question I had was that all printfs that were before execv() system call would get printed only after execv() got executed. And as @MYousefi Sir commented, it was because of buffer not being full. And as suggested, adding "\n" in printfs solved the problem.